# Create a gradient border in CSS3 as referenced

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am doing a gradient border of a div in css3. So far now I have done my coding like this

in css

```
.bot-left {
  position: relative;
}
.bot-left:before, .bot-left:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -3px;

}
.bot-left:before {
  top: -3px;
  width: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 0 0, from(#000), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, #000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(transparent, #000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, #000);
}
.bot-left:after {
  right: -3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#000), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #000, transparent);
}
```

in html

```
  <div class="bot-left" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></div>
```

But still I am not getting the exact match as reference. The reference image for the gradient border is attached with this

**UPDATE**
I want the background-color should be transparent.

[image]

Comment: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HIJuL no background color, but white over white will not be seen, so body needs a color

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to use the gradients as background instead of border images. The reason I am suggesting you to use this method is because `border-image` [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/border-image) by IE10. Where as you can implement this method to support IE9 as well, by using base64 encoded gradients.

Now, here am using two absolute positioned elements along with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements which are positioned absolute.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nHU24/)</kbd>

Here, you can refactor this to a great extent, I've not done that so that you can figure out how this works.

Also, if you want, you can wrap this inside a `position: relative;` container with a negative `z-index` set on the elements having class of  `.frame1` and `2` respectively.

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/nHU24/1/)</kbd>

```
body {
    background: #000;
}

.frame1,
.frame2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 25px;
}

.frame1:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    width: 1px;
}

.frame1:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    height: 1px;
}

.frame2:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    width: 1px;
}

.frame2:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    height: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For younger browser , you may use one single gradient, box-shadow and transparent border : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/cJLpb)**

CSS used for demo:

```
.bot-left {
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom right,
      #777,
      #555,
      #333,
      #111,
      #333,
      #555,
      #777) center;
  background-size:105% 105%;/* needs to lay under borders */
  box-sizing:border-box;/* keep borders inside width and height setted */
  border:1px transparent solid;/* background will show through */
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 500px black, 0 0 0 5px black;/* inset shadow will hide background gradient */
  margin:5px;/* optionnal: includes ouside box-shadow in space needed by element */
}
```

Comment: I want the background color to be in transparent.

Comment: Nope..I just want a border with gradient but the background color should be in transparent

Comment: @NewUser I see it black on your screen shot :)

Comment: this would do ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HIJuL , thanks for some feed back :)